# Python : IndexError

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a basic bubble sort algorithm in Python, here's the code:

```
novac = int(input("Enter number of vaccines : "))
strength = []
midicl = []
if novac in range(0,10):
    for x in range(0, novac-1):
        strength[x].append(int(input("Enter strength of vaccine {} :".format(x))))
        midicl[x].append(int(input(("Enter midichlorian count of patient {} :".format(x)))))
    for x in strength:
        for y in strength:
            if strength[x] < strength[y]:
                strength[x], strength[y] = strength[y], strength[x]
    print(strength)

else:
    print("A maximum of 10 vaccines are allowed")
```

And I'm getting the following error which implies that somehow my list index is out of bounds even after using the *list.append* method.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aakash/PycharmProjects/Midichlorian/Midichlo.py", line 6, in <module>
    strength[x].append(int(input("Enter strength of vaccine {} :".format(x))))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the below line

```
strength[x].append(int(input("Enter strength of vaccine {} :".format(x))))
midicl[x].append(int(input(("Enter midichlorian count of patient {} :".format(x)))))
```

to

```
strength.append(int(input("Enter strength of vaccine {} :".format(x))))
midicl.append(int(input(("Enter midichlorian count of patient {} :".format(x)))))
```

You do not need to index to append elements to a list.